# Thermopile reading very low in my gas fireplace

Tags: gas, fireplace

My gas fireplace failed to light this year, although the pilot was fine. I put my multimeter on the terminals and got about 150 mV. This was obviously too low, so I cleaned it and got maybe 160.

So I bought a new one and installed it. It give me 180 mV.

The pilot flame is right on the thermo, and by wiggling it and poking a bit I got a clearer flame and it went up to 200.

To make sure the thermo worked I put my BBQ lighter on it and it shot right up to 380. But it goes back down again as soon as I take it off.

Can anyone offer a suggestion on what I might do to get the values up?

Comment: What is the make and model of fireplace?  How old is it?

Comment: Is the pilot burning cleanly/correctly?

Comment: The pilot is working fine, at least visually, it is clean burning and stable. There is a screw that appears to be an adjustment for the pilot size, but doesn't seem to work. The fireplace is an Arrow DM10 built in 1993.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was actually the gas pipe, not the thermo. I guess it was corroded inside or had some dirt, but basically it was nothing more than not enough gas coming out. I put in a new line and presto, everything's perfect.